# how do I add line numbers to itemize environment?

Tags: lists, environments, line-numbering

I have an itemize environment that I use in a figure to describe, say, an algorithm or a process. I want to include line numbers, all aligned on the left most side of the figure so that I can refer to line x and line y in the figure (in the text itself). I thought it might be possible to do it with the `lineno` package, but it seems like it adds lines for the whole document.

Is there a way to localize that and say have something like:

```
  \begin{locallineno}
   some text with line numbers
  \end{locallineno}
```

Also, I would rather empty lines (blank lines) not be numbered, but that seems to be well taken care of in `lineno`.

EDIT: For example, I could have the following environment:

```
  \begin{locallineno}
       \begin{itemize}
         \item First clean the dishes.
         \item Now fill the tea pot with water.
              \begin{itemize}
                  \item First open the tea pot.
                  \item Turn on the tap
               \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
  \end{locallineno}
```

I would want it to have line numbers on the left for each bullet.

Comment: I'd recommend the `listings` package.

Comment: If the contents contain code that needs to be put in verbatim `listings` is among your best options. If you just want prose, you still need to specify newlines somehow, so the easiest option would just be to put `\item` at the beginning of each line and customising the spacing using for example the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen it seems like listings is for formatting source code. I am not using source code, but arbitrary itemized text...

Comment: @Bordaigorl so, I think what I would like to do is: create a new counter. reset it before every figure. change the itemize command so that it prints a number on the margin of the box it is in from the counter. Also, please note that I might have nested itemized items here, and they all should follow the same counter. I will have to think on how to do that in latex, I am not well-versed with the macros.

Comment: What about the `linesnumbered` option of `algorithm2e`?

Comment: @Bordaigorl That's for the algorithm package (linesnumbered), isn't it? I want to use my own itemized list, or something similar to an itemized list, not the algorithm environment.

Comment: @kloop: should the line numbers all be vertically aligned on the left margin, whether the itemize environment is nested or not, or can they be right shifted with the bullets if nested?

Comment: @kloop You mentioned listing an algorithm, which made me think you wanted to list an algorithm. Perhaps it's better if you provide an example of the output you want.

Comment: @Bernard I would rather they are all left aligned, irrespective of the nesting of the bullets.

Answer (score 4):

With the `lineno` package you can use the `linenumbers` environment to locally enable numbering:

[image: Line numbers on nested <code>itemize</code> environments]

You can also use `\nolinenumbers` to disable numbering for the nested `itemize` if desired:

[image: Line numbers for top level items only]

---

### Code: Use `linenumbers` environment

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{linenumbers}
       \begin{itemize}
         \item First clean the dishes.
         \item Now fill the tea pot with water.
              \begin{itemize}
                  \item First open the tea pot.
                  \item Turn on the tap
               \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{linenumbers}
 \lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Use `\nolinenumbers` to disable numbering

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{linenumbers}
       \begin{itemize}
         \item First clean the dishes.
         \item Now fill the tea pot with water.
              \begin{itemize}\nolinenumbers
                  \item First open the tea pot.
                  \item Turn on the tap
               \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{linenumbers}
 \lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with the `enumitem` package and its `wide` option. I create an itemize-like environment, `numitemise`, with a label width that increases with the level, that is aligned on the text left margin (`wide` option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{numln}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newlist{numitemise}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[numitemise]{wide}%
\setlist[numitemise, 1]{labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=2em, label=\stepcounter{numln}\makebox[2em]{\thenumln.\hfill\textbullet}, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
 \setlist[numitemise, 2]{labelindent=\dimexpr -2em-\labelsep\relax, labelwidth=\dimexpr 2em+\labelsep\relax, label=\stepcounter{numln}\makebox[\dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep\relax]{\thenumln.\hfill\textbullet}, leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargin+2\labelsep\relax}%

 \begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\begin{numitemise}%{A}
  \item The text of a first short item.
  \item The text of a second, longer item. The text of a second, longer item. The text of a second, longer item.
  \begin{numitemise}%{B}
    \item And now a nested subitem. It can be short or long. It can be short or long.
    \item Another nested subitem.
  \end{numitemise}
\item Back to a third item.
\end{numitemise}

\end{document}
```

[image]